# Kotlin K1 to K2 plugin migration. analysisCompleted, binding context slicing

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

I need a suggestion on K1->K2 Kotlin compiler plugin migration.

I have a K1-compatible plugin that overrides `AnalysisHandlerExtension::analysisCompleted` and uses a `bindingContext` to get a slice of `TYPE`s used in compilation:

```
bindingContext.getSliceContents(BindingContext.TYPE)
```

Full K1 plugin code snippet:

```
class Ext: AnalysisHandlerExtension {
  override fun analysisCompleted(
      project: Project,
      module: ModuleDescriptor,
      bindingTrace: BindingTrace,
      files: Collection<KtFile>
  ): AnalysisResult? {   
  ...
    bindingTrace.bindingContext.getSliceContents(BindingContext.TYPE).values.forEach {
      record(it)
    }
  ...

}
```

### Question

What is the most appropriate way to implement it using K2?

We likely need two things: first, an `analysisCompleted` analogue, and second, a `bindingContext.getSliceContents` analogue. Any suggestions?